# JavaScript: A countdown timer that uses only TIME

Tags: javascript, php, database, timer, countdown

Apologies, I know this question has been asked severally but none of the questions/answers meet my exact need. I have tried writing, Googling and even Stackoverflow.
My use-case is to start a timer using JavaScript (as gotten from the database using PHP) for a test to be taken immediately the student clicks on "Start Test", when the time is up, submission is made and result is collated unless the student submits before time.
A teacher enters the duration for the test in the format (also saved to DB as) "2:30:45" for 2hrs 30mins 45secs. I need this to countdown until its "0:00:00" before automatic submission is made.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Convert whatever time you want to seconds and use a `setTimeout()` function that calls a form submission function. However, any student could just disable it and work for as long as they want - JavaScript is client-side and easily mitigated.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me an example please.
Also, is there a better way to make sure the student isn't able to temper with the timer?

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("the_form").submit(); }, 9045000)` (JS timers use milliseconds) or something along those lines... but I'd probably just use the JS for an on-screen indicator of time remaining and have an actual *test expires* date-time for that user/test in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what level of trust you are giving your students, but the best idea to keep track of time spent on something like this is server side, and probably best to starting session for the duration of the test.

I would use a javascript function that asynchronously updates the time remaining. Also I would write a javascript that async updates the students submissions so less likely answers are lost (plus you can get more interesting statistics that way like how long students spend on answer)